# How to increase image size using Carousel in bootstrap 4?

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

How can I increase the image size as the photo? I have tried adding css code to increase the size but it increases the size to the right and overlaps the text on the right. I need the image to increase to the left  [image: Page]

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div id="carouselExampleControls" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
        <div class="carousel-inner">
          <div class="carousel-item active"> <img class="d-block w-100" src="Images/RakirakiSlide/slide1.jpg" alt="First slide"> </div>
          <div class="carousel-item"> <img class="d-block w-100" src="Images/RakirakiSlide/slide2.jpg" alt="Second slide"> </div>
          <div class="carousel-item"> <img class="d-block w-100" src="Images/RakirakiSlide/slide3.jpg" alt="Second slide"> </div>
          <div class="carousel-item"> <img class="d-block w-100" src="Images/RakirakiSlide/slide4.jpg" alt="Second slide"> </div>
          <div class="carousel-item"> <img class="d-block w-100" src="Images/RakirakiSlide/slide5.jpg" alt="Second slide"> </div>
        </div>
        <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="prev"> <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span> <span class="sr-only">Previous</span> </a> <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="next"> <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span> <span class="sr-only">Next</span> </a> </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

add this css code:

```
#carouselExampleControls .carousel-item img {
 width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: The image already has a `w-100` class so I don't think this will make any difference.

Comment: Ohh.. Didn't see it .. Sorry!